# Calling Firebase database function on app termination

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing app same like uber. When captain terminate app I need remove/update node on firebase database. After app termination can't send notification to captain that based on firebase database.

Comment: When you 'terminate', does that mean force-quitting (like if the app is frozen) or does it mean to quit the app in a normal way?

Comment: @Jay force quitting

Comment: You can handle that with onDisconnect or a presence system. See my comments to @sh-khan answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this except whenever the app is opened is to continuously  ping firebase with say like

```
"active":true
```

Then make a timer in your sever that makes it

```
"active":false
```

Comment: Would this be a good use for [onDisconnect](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works) or building a [Presence System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample)?